# test website compatibility with IE7

Tags: internet-explorer

I would like to see how my website renders in IE7. Unfortunately, my computer has IE8 installed, and I don't know how to downgrade to IE7. I've considered using the [IE Tab](http://ietab.mozdev.org/) Firefox plugin but reviews seem fairly mixed and I'm not sure how accurately it emulates IE7.

Answer (score 4):

I would use a virtual machine with internet explorer 7.

You can [download an image](http://www.microsoft.com/Downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=21eabb90-958f-4b64-b5f1-73d0a413c8ef&displaylang=en) from microsoft for free which has windows xp and ie 7 installed on it.

Comment: +1, I believe this is the best method.  I have tried many methods of IE7/IE6 testing, but a virtual machine (or real machine for that matter) always gives the most accurate results. IEtester and MultipleIE's have limitations which will not work right in tricky situations (such as cross-domain javascript on Facebook).

Answer (score 3):

We use [ietester](http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage) which allows you to test in all versions of IE and seems quite accurate

Answer (score 2):

You could use

```
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />
```

to make [IE8 fallback to](http://blogs.msdn.com/mikeormond/archive/2008/09/25/ie-8-compatibility-meta-tags-http-headers-user-agent-strings-etc-etc.aspx) [IE7 rendering mode](http://blogs.msdn.com/ie/archive/2008/06/10/introducing-ie-emulateie7.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

I've had good luck with [Xenocode](http://xenocode.com/browsers).  I wrote about it: [Xenocode and multiple IE's](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/200909/xenocode_and_multiple_ies.html).

Comment: Xenocode (http://spoon.net/browsers) has dropped support for iE, on request of Microsoft. IE 6, 7 and 8 can still be downloaded (see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4227959/938089?quick-browser-testing-internet-explorer-version-6-7-and-8)). However, it doesn't work for Windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the developer tools (F12) to switch the browser mode to IE7.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't there an option in IE 8 called [compatibility view](http://blogs.msdn.com/ie/archive/2009/03/12/site-compatibility-and-ie8.aspx), right next to the refresh button, that simulates how IE 7 looks.

Myself personally, since I am a Mac user and I hate getting on my virtual machine just to check something real quick, I always use this [Internet Explorer Net Renderer](http://ipinfo.info/netrenderer/).

Comment: Yeah, you are technically correct. However, ie 7 renders differently than the compatibility mode in ie 8. I have notice a bunch of differences when testing.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a free tool from Microsoft that allows you to do IE 6, IE 7 and IE 8 in a very neat comparison view: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=8e6ac106-525d-45d0-84db-dccff3fae677&displaylang=en